# How do I make my Mac stop responding to an Apple remote?

Tags: mac, remote-control

I've got a MacBook running OS X 10.5 and an Apple TV sitting next to each other.  The remote for the Apple TV is being picked up by the MacBook.  I want it to only control the Apple TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X 10.5: Go to `Security` in `System Preferences.app`, then select `Disable remote control infrared receiver` at the bottom.

newer versions of OS X: Go to `Security and Privacy` in `System Preferences.app`, then click on `Advanced` at the bottom and select `Disable remote control infrared receiver`.